# Can I visit or work in Singapore if I am HIV positive?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, health, singapore, working-visas, hiv

I worked in Singapore for 4 years (2004-2007).  Through the work permit renewal process, I was found positive for HIV. After that, I was sent back to Malaysia

Can I enter Singapore as a visitor? Can I work there?

Comment: If you are a Malaysian citizen, I suggest trying to enter via causeway. Although you definitely can't work or stay as a dependent, you shouldn't have problem entering as a visitor. However, its not sure that Singapore set any flag in their system for you.

Answer (score 8):

From [Action for Aids Singapore](https://afa.org.sg/law-and-hiv-in-singapore/#:%7E:text=HIV%20testing%20is%20usually%20required,will%20not%20be%20granted%20passes.):

> Tourists or short term visitors are not required to undergo an HIV test. HIV testing is usually required for applying for a work pass, long term visit pass, employment pass, or permanent residence. Those who are found to be HIV-positive will not be granted passes.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143213/discussion-on-answer-by-lambshaanxy-can-i-visit-or-work-in-singapore-if-i-am-hiv); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.